# adjust colour bar range to visible part of basemap contour plot

Tags: matplotlib, colorbar, matplotlib-basemap, contourf

I have a contour plot on a basemap and i wish to adjust the range of the colour bar so that they fit to the visible data. The default setting makes the colour range to fit to all data, i.e. also those which are not plotted. Is there a setting for this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, addcyclic, shiftgrid

myllcrnrlat=35
myurcrnrlat=65
myllcrnrlon=-45
myurcrnrlon=45
m = Basemap(projection='cyl', llcrnrlat=myllcrnrlat, urcrnrlat=myurcrnrlat,\
llcrnrlon=myllcrnrlon, urcrnrlon=myurcrnrlon, resolution='c')

lonsin=np.asarray(range(0,360,10))
latsin=np.asarray(range(-90,90,10))
valin=np.random.rand(len(latsin), len(lonsin))
valin[0,0]=5  #this is a value outside my basemap area and higher than all inside.
valin_cyclic, lons_cyclic = addcyclic(valin, lonsin)
valin_cyclic, lons_cyclic = shiftgrid(180., valin_cyclic, lons_cyclic, start=False)
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lons_cyclic, latsin)
x, y = m(lon2d, lat2d)

cs = m.pcolormesh(x, y, valin_cyclic,cmap=plt.get_cmap('autumn_r'))
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

Of couse I can use vmin, vmax by doing something like the following, but it seems rather long, so maybe there is a special setting?

```
lonsin_inbasemap=np.asarray([a for a in lonsin if myllcrnrlon <= a if a <= myurcrnrlon])
latsin_inbasemap=np.asarray([a for a in latsin if myllcrnrlat <= a if a <= myurcrnrlat])
valin_inbasemap_tmp = np.transpose(np.asarray([valin[:,a] for a in range(len(lonsin)) if lonsin[a] in lonsin_inbasemap]))
valin_inbasemap     = np.asarray([valin_inbasemap_tmp[a,:] for a in range(len(latsin)) if latsin[a] in latsin_inbasemap])
del(valin_inbasemap_tmp)

vmax=np.amax(valin_inbasemap)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x, y, valin_cyclic,vmax=vmax, cmap=plt.get_cmap('autumn_r'))
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mask some data that below some value.
For example, the minus data you would not want to show:
You can use ``

```
valin = np.ma.masked_less(valin_cyclic,0)
cmap1 = plt.cm,get_cmap("autumn_r")
cmap1.set_bad("w")

p =plt.pcolor((x, y,conc,cmap=cmap1,alpha =1,zorder =2)
```